# ¿se puede encriptar o proteger el código fuente PHP en caso de vender un proyecto?

Tags: php

He intentado instalar la extensión Blenc Encoder pero no me funciona, ni con la versión PHP 5.6, ¿existe alguna DLL que sirva para encriptar el codigo y que funcione el PHP del lado servidor o algún algoritmo que encripte el código por file_get_contents() y funcione de igual manera?

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, hay un método que se llama ofuscar el código y lo que hace es volver el código ilegible para una persona. El programa que te pongo de ejemplo es el PHP Encoder. (https://www.sourceguardian.com/). Funaiona así:

1. Se instala el programa y se ofusca el código que sea necesario.
2. Se installa un archivo dll en el servidor para que se pueda leer el código ofuscado (codificado).
3. Se sube el código ofuscado al servidor y ya tienes todo tú codigo protegido.

Queda mas o menos así. Aunque hay varios otros programas que hacen lo mismo, de los que he probado y por experiencia es el mejor, aunque no es gratuito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No conozco este método a fondo, pero quería añadir como comentario, que cualquier tipo de ofuscación, hasta dónde yo se, es reversible de una u otra forma y por tanto, no es seguro que nadie pueda ver o conseguir el código. Yo me plantearía vender el producto con el código, será más caro, pero te permite entregar el código sin problemas.

Comment: Este producto cuenta con algún prerrequisito? o se necesita algo para ser instalado?